# как из результата for сделать список в питоне?

Tags: python, списки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно ,чтобы столбик, который выводится после манипуляций с циклом for,стал списком ,чтобы я смогла найти максимальное значение.Как это сделать?

Comment: Лучше вместо картинки с кодом добавьте сам код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = [(D[i]+N[i]) // 2) for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.Это было так просто.